# Can General Feats be used for either ancestry or class feats?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e

I am working on a character concept for a rogue that needs more class feats and ancestry feats than the normal progression grants.

At 3rd level and every 4 levels after, my character gains a General feat, which [Archives of Nethys](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?Traits=78&NoSkills=True) says:

> A type of feat that any character can select, regardless of ancestry and class, as long as they meet the prerequisites. You can select a feat with this trait when your class grants a general feat.

Notably, neither ancestry feats nor class feats include the General tag.

One option that might be an option is the Ancestral Paragon feat, but it's a 3rd level feat to get a 1st level ancestry feat, so it's less than ideal, especially in the long-term.

Are there additional feats or rules that would allow me to swap General feats for class feats or ancestry feats?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Currently, there is no easy way to get the Feats you want

There are very limited options to take Feats that are not of the correct type (other than General Feats including most(all?) Skill Feats). Ancestral Paragon, Humans' General Training/Advanced General Training (Take General Feat as an Ancestry Feat) and Natural Ambition (Level 1 Class Feat as an Ancestry Feat) are pretty much it. There are a few similar effects, such as Halflings' Cultural Adaptability, Hobgoblins' Runtsage, Skeletons' "As in Life, So in Death" or Stonebounds' Elemental Existance, all of which give you Adopted Ancestry with an additional Feat from *that* Ancestry.

This could change as more content is released, but it is unlikely to allow you more Class Feats. There is a general hierarchy to Feats' relative usefulness of Class>General/Skill>Ancestry, with Class Feats being the most relevant and commonly useful, General/Skill Feats tending to be smaller bonuses or more circumstantial, and Ancestry Feats being a further step down. Of course, there exceptions such as Darkvision and permanent move speeds including flight, but as a whole they tend to be very circumstantial, a very small bonus, or a little of both.

Because of this, and depending on your GM's buy-in on the character and the specific Feats you're looking at, you might be able to request that they allow the Ancestry Feats be taken with a homebrewed version of [Ancestral Paragon](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=753) that allows you to take any lower level Ancestry Feat and can be taken multiple times.

### Variants

There is one optional ruleset, which my groups play with, called [Free Archetypes](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1333) that allows you to take a second Class Feat at each even level... but they can only be used for Dedication(s) and their Archetype Feats. Some Class Feats can be found on these other lists and it might allow you to meet your desired number, if your GM is amenable to the very reasonable power increase provided by the Variant.

There is another Variant, which I have not tried, called [Dual-Class PCs](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1328). This has much the same effect, but only for a Class that shares some of the Rogue's Feats. This will drastically affect the balance of the game, though, and should definitely be considered only if everyone is all-in on the idea.